# convert string with UTC offset to spark timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, datetime-format

How to store string `2018-03-21 08:15:00 +03:00` as a `timestamptype`, preserving the UTC offset, in spark?

tried below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([("2018-03-21 08:15:00 +03:00",)], ["timestamp"])
newDf= df.withColumn("newtimestamp", to_timestamp(col('timestamp'), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss XXX")
)
```

This prints `newtimestamp` column with value converted to UTC time i.e `2018-03-21 05:15:00`

How I can store this string as timestamp column in dataframe preserving offset i.e store same string as timestamp or store like `2018-03-21 08:15:00 +3000`

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the timestamp you obtain from the convertion to the desired pattern using `date_format`:

```
newDf = df.withColumn(
    "newtimestamp",
    to_timestamp(col('timestamp'), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss XXX")
).withColumn(
    "newtimestamp_formatted",
    date_format("newtimestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")
)

newDf.show(truncate=False)

#+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
#|timestamp                 |newtimestamp       |newtimestamp_formatted   |
#+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
#|2018-03-21 08:15:00 +03:00|2018-03-21 06:15:00|2018-03-21 06:15:00 +0100|
#+--------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @blackbishop, As you can see the time gets converted automatically, and offset is not +0300 in final result. I wish to store the same date and offset (+3) without any time conversion as a timestamptype . Is it possible?

Comment: yes, but we receive records with different timestampoffset in the source, i.e one record with `2018-03-21 08:15:00 +03:00` and another record with `2019-05-21 00:15:00 +01:00`. So I wish to store the record as a timestamptype preserving the same offset value., i.e +03 for first record and +01 for second record. If I set `timezone` to any particular location, spark will convert the original datetime to that offset losing the original offset value.